# What is the default rEFInd OS Stanza for booting Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, macintosh, refind

I have a macbook with yosemite installed, and I just added a partition of arch linux that I boot into using rEFInd. Arch was giving me an error because rEFInd boots by default using a "`ro`" parameter instead of a "`rw`" parameter. I edited `refind.conf`, adding an OS stanza for Arch but with "`rw`" as an option instead, and when I use the listing when booting, it gives an error.

I'm looking for the "default stanza" that `refind` uses for Arch when no stanza is manually given, so that I can match mine to it.

Here's my OS stanza:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    icon     /EFI/BOOT/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_arch.png
    volume   4:
    loader   /boot/vmlinuz-linux
    initrd   \boot\initramfs-linux
    options  "root=UUID=F0778b29-8295-4d1a-b209-8582ebfe1051 rootfstype=ext4 rw add_efi_memmap"
}
```

Also, I need to remove the `.efi` for arch so that I don't have two listings for Arch when I boot... where is that located? Is it on the arch partition or on the EFI boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

About the duplicate entries, you should change the `scanfor` option on `refind.conf`. It is well documented in there, but in your case you would need to set it to use just the `manual` option, this way:

`scanfor manual`

About the default stanza for Arch, you can use the provided ones, just adapt them to your needs. The default one is probably pretty basic too.